# Regex to extract digits followed by specific word

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Using Regex, I want to extract digits which are followed by a specific word.

The number of digits is not finite.

Sample input:

```
My address is 1234@abc.com and you can send SMS to me.
```

Expected Result.

```
1234
```

In this case, the specific word is `@abc.com`, and the digits followed by this word need to be extracted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the regular expression groups : [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx).

In C#, try this :

```
string pattern = @"(\d+)@abc\.com";
string input = "My address is 15464684@abc.com and you can send SMS to me";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

// Get the first named group.
Group group1 = match.Groups[1];
Console.WriteLine("Group 1 value: {0}", group1.Success ? group1.Value : "Empty");
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to match 1234@abc.com and use a grouping to extract the digits:

```
(\d+)\@abc.com
```

Answer (score 0):

`.* (\d+)@abc\.com .*` should work.